# When will Gnome 2.32.1 be available?

Tags: 10.10, gnome

When will gnome 2.32.1 packages be released on maverick?

Answer (score 3):

In general GNOME updates go through the [Stable Release Updates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) process. Searching through the [pending updates](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/pending-sru.html) shows some 2.32.1 packages there. Here's an [example](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+source/empathy/2.32.1-0ubuntu1).

Generally speaking looking at the meta package usually isn't enough, not all GNOME packages follow the same naming convention, some tarballs might not have a new release, etc. However our desktop team works closely with the GNOME release team on stable updates.

In certain cases the SRU/desktop/release team might only cherry pick fixes from the upstream point release and backport them. In cases like this it will be mentioned in the package changelog.